# How to make pyspark df to nested array with group by

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a dataframe looks like this,

```
TEST_schema = StructType([StructField("date", StringType(), True),\
                              StructField("id1", StringType(), True),\
                              StructField("id2", StringType(), True),\
                              StructField("col1", IntegerType(), True),
                             StructField("col2", IntegerType(), True),
                             StructField("col3", FloatType(), True),
                         StructField("col4", StringType(), True)])
TEST_data = [('2020-08-01','aa','123',3,5,0.5,'a'),('2020-08-02','aa','123',-1,4,0.0,'b'),('2020-08-01','bb','456',-1,3,0.0,'b'),\
                 ('2020-08-02','bb','456',-1,3,0.0,'d'),('2020-08-03','bb','456',-1,4,0.0,'a'),('2020-08-01','aa','456',-1,5,0.0,'z'),('2020-08-02','aa','456',-1,5,0.0,'g')]
rdd3 = sc.parallelize(TEST_data)
TEST_df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(TEST_data, TEST_schema)
TEST_df = TEST_df.withColumn("date",to_date("date", 'yyyy-MM-dd'))
TEST_df.show() 

+----------+---+---+----+----+----+----+
|      date|id1|id2|col1|col2|col3|col4|
+----------+---+---+----+----+----+----+
|2020-08-01| aa|123|   3|   5| 0.5|   a|
|2020-08-02| aa|123|  -1|   4| 0.0|   b|
|2020-08-01| bb|456|  -1|   3| 0.0|   b|
|2020-08-02| bb|456|  -1|   3| 0.0|   d|
|2020-08-03| bb|456|  -1|   4| 0.0|   a|
|2020-08-01| aa|456|  -1|   5| 0.0|   z|
|2020-08-02| aa|456|  -1|   5| 0.0|   g|
+----------+---+---+----+----+----+----+
```

and I want to convert dataframe looks like this group by id1 and id2 basically. the resulted set looks like this..

```
|id1|id2|             col1                |           col2                 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|aa |123|[ [2020-08-01,3],[2020-08-02,-1] ]| [[2020-08-01,5],[2020-08-02,4]]
|bb |456|[ [2020-08-01,-1],[2020-08-02,-1].........
```

and so on... and could you show using those arrays and do some real simple calculations? maybe on `id1 =aa` and `id2 = 123` do col1 + col2, respect to the date. so calculation column would have like
[ [2020-08-01,**8**],[2020-08-02,**3**] ]

Answer (score 0):

You can't do an array of date and sum of the col1 and col2 if your using pyspark since the date and the integer are different types. however you can do a map of date and sum, groupby and see if it fits your need

```
TEST_df.withColumn("dateColSum", create_map(col("date"), col("col1")+col("col2") )    ).groupBy("id1", "id2").agg(collect_list("dateColSum")).show(truncate=False)
+---+---+---------------------------------------------------------+
|id1|id2|collect_list(dateColSum)                                 |
+---+---+---------------------------------------------------------+
|aa |456|[[2020-08-01 -> 4], [2020-08-02 -> 4]]                   |
|aa |123|[[2020-08-01 -> 8], [2020-08-02 -> 3]]                   |
|bb |456|[[2020-08-01 -> 2], [2020-08-02 -> 2], [2020-08-03 -> 3]]|
+---+---+---------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: could you change the whole thing to array? maybe like col1 = [ [aa,123,2020-08-01,3] [aa,123,2020-08-02,-1]] col2 = [[aa,123,2020-08-01,5] , [aa,123,2020-08-02,4] ] .. and so on?

Comment: can be done, but you will get all strings since different types in an array in pyspark won't work

Comment: so how do i do the addition and subtraction and stuff and create a new column? could you show how it's done?

Comment: as you see in the above code, the map will has a sum of col1 and col 2 for each date.